# Provide MbTiles from GeoServer with mutliple vector Layers

Tags: geoserver, layers, mapbox, mbtiles

Is there a way to serve pbfs tiles by loading a mbtiles file (multiple vector layers) into the GeoServer?

For this we used before Klokantech TileServer Gl to offer big mbtiles (osm vector tiles) to load it into mapbox-gl.
Now we want to move to GeoServer, and the question is if we may only use GeoServer.

I find different GeoServer extentions and there are some question marks:
- What is the `GeoServer MBTiles Data Store` exactly? only Images, or also vector data?
- Does `Vector Tiles Extension` also support multiple layers? And will it also work with mbtiles file?

Comment: You seem to have missed the point of the mbTiles WMS output format, it is designed to allow you to server layers as new mbTiles as a response to a WMS request, not simply pass through existing tiles. Maybe you should rephrase your question with a description of what you want to achieve rather than a question about a tool.

Comment: @IanTurton: Thanks. Means mbTiles WMS, that it will be as an image or will it be also vector layers?
And yes i thought it would be possible to offer mbtiles files (vector layers) thourgh this service

Comment: it will produce vector tiles but not ones that match the input tiles. It will process the layer you request into vector tiles for you. Usually that layer is in postgis or a shapefile

Comment: so only one layer? It is not possible to select multiple?